# Show up a panel with slide effect when there is focus on specific input box

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to implement (vertical slide in) show effect on a output panel when there is a focus on a textbox. (Initially the outputPanel should not be visible on screen, but when there is a focus on the input box, the outputPanel must show up with a slide in effect.)

```
    <p:inputTextarea>
        <p:effect event="focus" for="inputPanel" type="slide"/>
    </p:inputTextarea>

    <p:outputPanel id="inputPanel" style="display: none;" >
        ......
    </p:outputPanel>
```

---

## Using:

Primefaces 3.0 M3 Snapshot
JSF 2.0 with Facelets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the PrimeFaces guide [here](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html).

Use `f:param` to provide parameters to configure the animation.

Check this [JQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects) to learn about the parameters for the effects.

```
<p:inputTextarea>
    <p:effect event="focus" for="inputPanel" type="slide">
        <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" />
        <f:param name="direction" value="'up'" />
    </p:effect>
    <p:effect event="blur" for="inputPanel" type="slide">
        <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />
        <f:param name="direction" value="'up'" />
    </p:effect>
</p:inputTextarea>

<p:outputPanel id="inputPanel" layout="block" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; display: none;">
    <p:panel header="Panel inside OutputPanel" >
        <h1>Applying effect on output-panel.</h1>
    </p:panel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Also for the `<p:outputPanel` specify the attribute `layout` with the value of `"block"` to make PrimeFaces render a `DIV` instead of `SPAN` because the default value for `layout` attribute is `"inline"`.

Comment: Thanks @BheshG ! I am no longer using the hide effect on blur, and thus each time the focus returns back to inputTextArea, the effect is shown on the already visible outputPanel, which doesnt look very nice. Thus I wanted to show up the effect only when the outputPanel was hidden. Is there any way I set this condition for the effect to be displayed ?