# Effect that works only when the panel is invisible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

A few days ago I posted a question :

[**`How to show up an outputPanel with slide effect when there is focus on specific input box?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103226/show-up-a-panel-with-slide-effect-when-there-is-focus-on-specific-input-box)

I got the solution to the above problem but another problem appeared before me. Each time the focus returned back to `inputTextArea` from some other element, the effect is again shown on the already visible `outputPanel`, which doesnt look very nice.

Thus I want to show up the effect only when the `outputPanel` was hidden & not everytime the focus returned to the`inputTextArea`. Is there any way, I can set this condition for the effect to be shown?

---

## I'm Using:-

Primefaces 3.0 M3 Snapshot
JSF 2.0 with Facelets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Primefaces, but in jQuery you can do

```
if (!$("element").is(":visible")) 
{
//do something if element is not visibile
}
```

or

```
if ($("element").not(":visible")) 
{
//do something if element is not visibile
}
```